# How to make sure the logs is stored when the app crash and allow to send to developer in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Sometimes, when the app crash, there is an option to see the crash log for the app and send to the developer.

How do I do this in flutter app?

Comment: Doesn't Crashlytics work in that?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently Sentry support for Flutter

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sentry

Firebase crashlytics support is work in progress.